# When i save my illustrator poster the black background turns to white

Tags: adobe-illustrator

My poster has a black background with text and images (font in colour white) on the top. When i save the poster only the images appear and the background has turned white, subsequently the font which was white over the top disappears. How do i save the illustrator poster with a black background?
Thank you

Comment: Probably a layer issue? Turn on all your necesary layers?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the `Simulate Color Paper` option in the preferences. Draw a black box behind everything.

Simulate color paper is to *simulate* the paper you are printing on... unless you are actually printing on a black substrate with white ink, don't use it. And even if you *are* using a black substrate (such as a black t-shirt for silkscreening) you *still* want the art to print positive, so you'd set it up black on white, not white on black.